# How to delete a linkedlist in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a linked list structure for a feed scenario. Here i have my feeds persisted in the linked-list in neo4j. This is working fine. However, there might be a need to delete the whole product, so I am trying to come up with a cypher that can delete the product and the related linked list for feeds in one query.
This query returns me correct data

```
match p = (i:Item {uuid:"d98c299d-239b-40d1-ac2f-01a80ac36db4"})-[:LATEST]-(latestComment), latestComment-[:NEXT*0..]-(olders) return i, latestComment, olders;
```

based on these lines, I tried writing a delete query and its certain variations using foreach, but nothing seems to be working.

```
match p = (i:Item {uuid:"d98c299d-239b-40d1-ac2f-01a80ac36db4"})-[:LATEST]-(latestComment), latestComment-[:NEXT*0..]-(olders) delete i, latestComment, olders;
```

error:

```
Node record Node[13349,used=false,rel=26286,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships
```

a variation with foreach

```
match (i:Item {uuid:"d98c299d-239b-40d1-ac2f-01a80ac36db4"})-[:LATEST]-(latestComment), latestComment-[:NEXT*0..]-(olders) delete i, foreach (old in olders | delete old)
```

clearly there is something wrong, but I am not getting enough pointers towards the possible error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a node, you must also delete all relationships touching that node. You queries do not do that.

In your case, since you want to delete the entire path, you might be able to simply do this:

```
MATCH p =(i:Item { uuid:"d98c299d-239b-40d1-ac2f-01a80ac36db4" })-[latest:LATEST]-(latestComment)-[:NEXT*0..]-(olders)
DELETE p;
```

However, if any node in the path has relationships that are not also in the path, then the above query need to be modified to include those extra relationships.